# Analytic sets are Lebesgue measurable

Tags: lebesgue-measure, descriptive-set-theory

Analytic subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are projections of Borel sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I'm trying to understand a proof that these sets are always  Lebesgue measurable.

One can first prove that analytic sets $(\Sigma_1^1)$ are equal to $\mathcal{A}(\Pi_1^0)$ where $\mathcal{A}$ denotes the [Souslin operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suslin_operation), and $\Pi^0_1$ is the pointclass of closed sets. Then, one shows that Lebesgue measurable sets are closed under the Souslin operation. Doesn't it then follow by monotinicity that $\Sigma^1_1 = \mathcal{A}(\Pi_1^0) \subset \mathcal{A}(\{measurable\}) = \{measurable\}$?

Why do some authors mention the additional step that, in light of the idempotence of the Souslin operation, $\mathcal{A}(\Sigma_1^1)=\Sigma_1^1$ ?

See for example, corollary $13.5$ [here](http://www.personal.psu.edu/jsr25/Spring_11/Lecture_Notes/dst_lecture_notes_2011_Regularity-Analytic.pdf), or the mention of $4.1.14$ in Theorem $4.3.1$ of Srivastava. "A Course on Borel Sets".

Comment: Your argument looks sound.

Comment: I mean, the fact that $\mathcal{A}(\Sigma_1^1)=\Sigma_1^1$ is itself interesting.

Comment: Yeah, idempotence is interesting, but the proof is pretty involved (constructing a bunch of compatible bijections $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}\times (\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}})^{\mathbb{N}}\to\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$) and I didn't get why they included it in the discussion. But I guess it's not necessary?

Comment: I've removed the link to Srivastava. "A Course on Borel Sets" as this book is protected by copyright and not public domain.

Comment: Yes, idempotence is not used in the proof in spite of how Corollary 13.5 is written. Of course, we get all $\mathcal A\mathbf\Sigma^1_1$ sets are measurable, and without knowing idempotence this looks like a potentially stronger result, but that is a separate issue.

Comment: Ohk thanks. If someone wants to put in 'The additional step is not necessary' as an answer, I'm willing to accept and upvote.

Comment: @SirWilfredLucas-Dockery You should post the answer yourself. You've done all the work after all and it's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question on this platform. ;-)

Comment: @StefanMesken I agree that what you propose is perfectly acceptable, but after the OP did exactly that, the answer was deleted ("from review"). I've voted to undelete the answer.

Comment: @AndreasBlass That, unfortunately, didn't quite go as I'd hoped it would. I agree with the reviews that the answer should be more self-contained. But I still think OP should get credit. The best course of action, in my opinion, is for OP to improve the answer and then have it undeleted and accepted.

Comment: @StefanMesken It seems to me that making the answer self-contained would amount to copying into the answer the argument already given in the question.

Comment: @AndreasBlass In essence that will likely be the case. But I bit of additional verbosity would likely still improve the quality of this thread and satisfy the reviewers. It's a people problem -- not a mathematical one ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try to summarise the comments to give an answer:

Despite how the proofs in the references are framed, you only need to make two arguments. First you show that any Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the continuous image of the 'universal' Polish space $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$. It then follows that $\Sigma_1^1=\mathcal{A}(\Pi_1^0)$. Second, you use the completeness property of Lebesgue measurable sets to prove that they are closed under the Souslin operation. The result should then follow.

The idempotence of the Souslin operation, while interesting in its own right, is not necessary here. For anyone who's interested, it can be proved by constructing some clever bijections $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}\times (\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}})^{\mathbb{N}}\to {\mathbb{N}}^{\mathbb{N}}, \ \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N} $ and $\mathbb{N}^{<\mathbb{N}} \to \mathbb{N}^{<\mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: I think that it is better for the answer to be somewhat self-contained. In particular it is best not to make people have to go read a pdf to understand how an argument goes.